# SharedPreferences error when updating app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

When updating my application i get this error, only sometimes.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

`at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:354)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)
    at it.veneto.arpa.controller.Controller.verifyBulletin(Controller.java:377)
    at it.veneto.arpa.controller.Controller.retrieveBulletin(Controller.java:509)
    at it.veneto.arpa.controller.Controller.verifyBulletin(Controller.java:394)
    at it.veneto.arpa.controller.Controller.retrieveBulletin(Controller.java:509)
    at it.veneto.arpa.controller.Controller.verifyBulletin(Controller.java:394)
    at it.veneto.arpa.controller.Controller.retrieveBulletin(Controller.java:509)
    at it.veneto.arpa.controller.Controller.verifyBulletin(Controller.java:394)`

on line 377 there is:

`SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: `java.lang.StackOverflowError` occurs when there is recursive call for a method. Check for any recursive calls.

Comment: verifyBulletin calls retrieveBulletin calls verifyBulletin calls retrieveBulletin... They call each other in infinite circles. You need to figure out why and fix that. Without seeing these both methods we cannot help you

Comment: @NobuGames verifyBullettin call retrieveBulletin to get object saved on sharedPreferences and assign it to a variable.
In retrieveBulletin if this variable is null, verifyBulletin is invoked.
I suppose that sharedprefrence was corrupeted on update.

Comment: Data loss or corruption can happen but your code must be able to cope with that. Can you post these two methods? It should be possible to fix that even with unexpected input from SharedPreferences

Comment: @NobuGames ty! If the object is not initialized with data retrieved from the sharedPreferences then i recreate sharedPreferences data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to a server (I am assuming because of *retrieveBulletin* method) again and again, try waiting (Thread.sleep(TIME_OUT);) for a second or two before you try again. Have a maximum number of tries. Say if you tried 10 times already and still didn't receive a response or any valid response, try handling that situation rather than forever trying. If you don't, this will eventually result to an insufficient stack space and you will end up getting the error you are receiving.

Based from your comment, similar situation - bad recursive call without handling the worst scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `verifyBulletin` and `retrieveBulletin` are calling each-other infinite times. Make sure that they are not calling each-other or if they call each-other there is an end condition. If the end condition is fulfilled do not call the other method.